# Sprites in Internet Explorer 6/7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, png, sprite

I cant seem to make my sprites work correctly in IE 7 and below. (IE 9 works fine)
Below is my CSS:

```
#info 
{
    width:100%;
    height:77px;
    background:url('../img/ck_sprite.png')no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
#info:hover
{ 
    width:100%;
    background:url('../img/ck_sprite.png')no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -300px;
    cursor: default;
    float:left;
}
```

**There's two more classes like this**

I have tried to search the place for fixes to this problem, the solutions just does not apply for my problem.

EDIT: Sorry, i didnt describe my actual problem. The image does not display at all in IE.

Here is my html code:

```
              <div id="info">
              </div>        

                    <asp:Literal ID="litInfo" runat="server" />        



              <div id="bestilling">
              </div>          
                    <asp:Literal ID="litBestilling" runat="server" />          


              <div id="kontakt">

                    <asp:Literal ID="litKontakt" runat="server" />
```

As you can see, im coding the site in C#. The literals are placed outside of the div's because the only thing they should contain is the image. (They work as headlines)

Comment: please show us ur live demo that would be much better....

Comment: What is the actual problem. Sprites not displaying? Displaying in the wrong place? You should have a space between your closing bracket and your 'no-repeat' declaration.

Comment: ahh the old 'not working' error..

Comment: What is the problem? Why have you shown us two styles? Is error happened in normal r hover state?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't supply your **HTML**, so I'm going to assume your tag the ID is applied to is not an anchor tag?

IE6/7 only supports `:hover` pseudo on anchor tags.

This should work:

```
a#info 
{
    width:100%;
    height:77px;
    background:url('../img/ck_sprite.png')no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
a#info:hover
{ 
    width:100%;
    background:url('../img/ck_sprite.png')no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -300px;
    cursor: default;
    float:left;
}
```

...if your **HTML** is:

```
<p><a id="info" href="#">Hello World</a></p>
```

Hope that works? Give some further information for a better answer!

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

My html looks like this:

              <div id="bestilling">
              </div>

It's just an empty DIV, the text is written out in a Literal (The site is coded in C#)

Comment: A little update:
I tried to apply the <a> tags. It didnt work though.

Comment: Could you create a JS fiddle to mess with please? Will be much easier.